# Problema com crivo de Eratóstenes - JAVA

Tags: java

Meu professor passou a seguinte classe para implementação do crivo de Eratóstenes, mas deu instruções muito vagas de como devíamos fazê-lo, embora tenha deixado muito claro que só devíamos mexer nos métodos `getPrimes()` e `findPrimes()` e não no restante do código.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a chegar a resolução desse exercício?

Segue o código como está de acordo com a minha melhor tentativa de resolução:

```
package javaapplication1;

/**
 * Essa classe encontra numeros primos pelo metodo do
 * crivo de Eratostenes
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Object
 * @author 
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Sieve
{   
    /** 
     * numero de primos encontrados
     */
    private int count = 0;

    /** 
     * arrays de primos (true se o numero i na posicao [i] eh primo)
     */
    private boolean[] primes;

    /**
     * O construtor define a quantidade maxima de numeros primos que serao
     * gerados pelo crivo de Eratostenes
     * 
     * @param size Define numero entre 0 e size-1 serao verificados 
     *             se sao primos ou nao
     */
    public Sieve(int size) 
    {
        primes = new boolean[ size ];
        // assumir, inicialmente, que todos numeros sao primos
        for ( int index = 0; index < primes.length; index++ )
        {   
            primes[ index ] = true;
        }
        // encontrar os numeros primos
        findPrimes();
    }

    /**
     * @return o numero de primos encontrados
     */
    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * @return array contendo true para os numeros que sao primos
     */
    public boolean [] getPrimes()
    {   // sua implementacao vem aui...
          return primes;
    }

    /**
     * Encontra primos pelo metodo do crivo de Eratostenes.
     * Ao final do metodo, o array primes contem true apenas para os 
     * numeros primos e count contem o numero de primos encontrados.
     */
    private void findPrimes()
    {   // sua implementacao vem aui...
             for(int i = 2; i <=primes.length; i++){
        if(primes[i]){
            for(int j = i; i*j <= primes.length; j++)
                primes[i*j] = false;
        }
    }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    { 
      Sieve s = new Sieve( 16 );
      boolean[] p = s.getPrimes();
      for ( int index = 2; index < p.length; index++ )
         if ( p[ index ] )
            System.out.printf( "%d eh primo.\n", index );
      System.out.printf( "\n%d primos encontrados.\n", s.getCount() );
   } // end main

} // end class Sieve
```

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crivo_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes
Tenta implementar as instruções no metodo findPrimes(). No metodo getPrimes vc so retorna o array com os numeros primos encontrados.

Comment: @WagnerSoares Estou recebendo Exception in thread `"main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` depois de implementar o código, editado no post original

Comment: Alguém poderia me explicar porque esta pergunta foi fechada? Para mim ela é perfeitamente clara. É verdade que a versão original tinha alguns problemas que até justificariam os primeiros votos de fechamento, mas a forma como ela está agora (e estava assim antes de receber o último voto de fechamento) me parece ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu algoritmo está quase certo. Você só cometeu um errinho bobo no `findPrimes()`:

```
         for(int i = 2; i <=primes.length; i++){
```

```
        for(int j = i; i*j <= primes.length; j++)
```

Nesses dois laços, era para usar o `<` ao invés de `<=`. Trocando ambos por `<`, o seu algoritmo funciona e lista os números primos.

O algoritmo funciona até você usar `new Sieve(46349)`. Se você usar `new Sieve(46350)` ou um número maior, daí o algoritmo falha devido ao overflow.

Há ainda o problema que no final, o algoritmo sempre mostra isso:

> 0 primos encontrados.

Isso daí ocorre porque em lugar nenhum você está colocando um `count++`.

Comment: Olá, gostaria de agradecer pela ajuda! Apenas adicionei `count++` no laço do `findPrimes()` e deu tudo certo.
Mais uma vez, obrigado!

Comment: @LeonardoFelixdaSilva Se a minha resposta serviu, não se esqueça de marcá-la como aceita/correta ao clicar no ✅ ao lado da resposta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa  Em vez de ir até `primes.length`, não pode ir até a raiz quadrada disso? Não olhei em detalhes o problema, mas normalmente para achar um primo eu faço um laço que inicia com `i=2` enquanto `i<=Math.sqrt(numero)`.

Comment: @eightShirt Não. No algoritmo padrão de divisões sucessivas você certamente faria isso, mas este não é este o algoritmo aqui. O crivo de Erastótenes não funciona assim, pois nele você começa com uma lista de a todos os números do intervalo desejado, assumindo que todos os números são inicialmente primos e vai elimando dessa lista os números que são múltiplos de outros números. Observe que o algoritmo de divisões sucessivas procura por divisores enquanto que o crivo de Erastótenes procura por múltiplos.

Comment: Copy that. Entendi, obrigado.